Cannot access embeddings endpoint on vLLM hosting llama3-8b-instruct
I'm using vllm to run llama3-8b-instruct on a machine, I can access the chat endpoint, but when I access the embedding endpoint using following code I get NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'detail': 'Not Found'}
from openai import OpenAI

# Modify OpenAI's API key and API base to use vLLM's API server.
openai_api_key = "EMPTY"
openai_api_base = "http://10.244.191.18:8000/v1"

client = OpenAI(
    # defaults to os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
    api_key=openai_api_key,
    base_url=openai_api_base,
)

models = client.models.list()
model = models.data[0].id

responses = client.embeddings.create(input=[
    "Hello my name is",
    "The best thing about vLLM is that it supports many different models"
], model=model)

for data in responses.data:
    print(data.embedding)  # list of float of len 4096

vLLM error log:
INFO:     172.30.230.216:52870 - "POST /v1/embeddings HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
Code snippet is from vllm document: https://docs.vllm.ai/en/latest/getting_started/examples/openai_embedding_client.html

The embeddings endpoint was added in version 0.4.3 released on June 1, 2024. Make sure you have this recent version installed.

Tried 0.4.3 and got new error message with the same code: BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'object': 'error', 'message': 'base64 encoding is not currently supported', 'type': 'BadRequestError', 'param': None, 'code': 400}

Well that's progress! Try with encoding_format='float'. That's the default both in OpenAI and vLLM, so I don't know why it would try for base64 in your case. But perhaps you can override it. Go for float!
